# Which set does bag 9 being to?

Tags: sets, set-identification

We were recently gifted a lot of LEGO and have an unopened bag in among all the pieces.  We are trying to identify what set it belongs with.  Any one have any idea which set it might be?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like some castle pieces and ladders there...

Answer (score 8):

It is from set [70404 King's Castle](http://www.bricklink.com/SL/70404-1.jpg?1) from 2013. Hope that helps.

[image]